# mysqldump without password prompt - but for different hosts and users

Tags: login, mysql

I googled a while but couldn't find an answer.
Although it is often explained, how you simply could put a .my.cnf into your /root and make your funny full database dumps without having to enter a password.

Example:

```
mysqldump --complete-insert --opt -Q -h example.com -u db_user -p databasename > dump.sql
```

Now, the following would help me with this - and only this - user:

```
[mysqldump]
host=example.com
user=db_user
password=password
```

I expected it would be possible to define several users and passwords for different hosts.
Maybe by using the block multiple times? Couldn't find anything written about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by define another `.cnf` file:

```
[mysqldump]
host=example2.com
user=db_user2
password=password2
```

and use [--defaults-extra-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html#option_general_defaults-extra-file) option:

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/path/to/another.cnf --complete-insert --opt -Q > dump.sql
```

Comment: Thx, it worked!